# Is building a hackintosh computer haram?

Tags: halal-haram, software, technology

A hackintosh computer is a standard personal computer that runs Apple Mac OS X as opposed to Windows or Linux.
Hackintosh computers are a violation of the Apple EULA, as it states that "OS X shouldn't be installed on non-Apple-branded computers (Macintosh computers).

However, there are grounds to believe that this condition is only there to deter companies from making such computers and selling them for a profit (as in Psystar Inc. in the United States, later sued in court by Apple), not really to deter individuals.

My question is:
Is the EULA valid?

Is the EULA enforceable in Islam? (like, does it apply if I remove it from the operating system?). It says that you automatically agree to its terms by merely using the operating system. Isn't that an enforced contract?

The condition of the non-Apple-branded computer seems to be a monopoly over the operating system (I sold the product to you BUT you can only use it however we wish and ONLY on our computers). Is such monopoly halal?

The company has R&D centers in Israel. Does that make any difference (supporting Zionists by using a product which may or may not be developed in Israel vs. harming somebody who supports Zionists by abusing their product?)

Edit: EULAs are not enforceable in my country. Please check yours for such enforceability.

Comment: Is that legal in the country where you are residing?

Comment: Yeah, it is. I edited my post above.

Comment: @Envayo 1. Fair enough. 2. a. That's logic, but that's if the terms are fair. Where's the fairness in FORCING somebody into a contract with unfair conditions? Moreover, have you got Islamic texts to back your claim? b. "Don't do something to others that you wouldn't want done to yourself" Does that make people "not do" stuff that you wouldn't want to be done to you? That makes moral sense, but not really applicable in real life with people.

Comment: Really awesome! Well, nobody forces us to use Apple's operating systems, but Windows is expensive for many and no longer offers the bang-for-buck (it is a totally expensive, constant, and prolonged headache nowadays). One more point: As a contract, is it valid with a monopoly (احتكار)-type condition?

Comment: Is Apple OK to allow home users like you to have a Hackingtosh? If not then you have got to ask yourself, Is stealing from someone Halal or Haram, even if you are stealing from an infidel?

Comment: I have a common sense opinion. I also have the same problem. I would suggest using Ubuntu. If you continue using Hackintosh you will be hooked to MacOS which in long run can be bad for you. On the other hand Windows is probably stealing your data. If you continue using open source then in short time hopefully you will get used to it and also it is liberating.

Answer (score 1):

Once you purchase a product, it's halal for you to dispose of your possession as you see fit, and the seller cannot place a condition on how you will or won't use your possession. Therefore a contract that attempts to limit what you can and can't do with the product after you purchase it is not enforceable Islamically.

The only consideration would be the legality of it in the jurisdiction in which you live, but you've already stated EULAs are not valid in that jurisdiction.